# VBA Send email when cell date entered changes

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm having an issue with this coding. I'm trying to code it so that an email will automatically be sent when the a date is entered on a certain sheet on Column B.

Essentially what is going to happen is that employees will get new assignments everyday. The date will change by the date that is entered.

I would love it if the code would recognize the current date that was entered and send that an email to a specific employee. Here's a sample code that I have but it's only set to numeric value and I don't know how to change it. Please help!

This code is in the specific worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A:A"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value >= 1 Then
            Call Send_Email
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This code goes in the module

```
   Sub Send_Email()
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi All" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "You may have new cases." & vbNewLine & _
              "Please review and disposition them." & vbNewLine & _
              "Thank you"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "Calheers Unit"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "New Case Assignments"
        .Body = strbody
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the date will change by the date that is entered mean? How would we find the correct employee to send the email to?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the entered date is today just check if the *target.value* equals to *Date*. *Date* represents today date in VBA like *=Today()* in excel.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column = 2 Then               'If target is in column B
        If Target.Value = Date Then         'If the target value is today
           Call Send_Email
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```